# SignalR and NServiceBus in a WebFarm

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, nservicebus

I am trying to understand if/how this works.

Can SignalR and NServiceBus be used together to support full duplex on a web farm where the request could be sent from a server then later the response would come back but the user may be on another server.

The use case for this would be a user submits a form which then takes a while to process say 3-5 minutes.  During that time the user is doing other things and could be switching between servers due to load balancing.  Once the process is complete it would send a response back which would show a notification to the user.

If there are some articles on this that would be great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Allow me to refer you to Roy Cornelissen's great blog post on this very topic:

http://roycornelissen.wordpress.com/2013/03/11/an-nservicebus-backplane-for-signalr/

Comment: Thanks a lot Udi, for your kind words and the link to my post. I have just now updated it to SignalR 1.1.2, which contains the final release of the ScaleoutMessageBus architecture. It has changed quite a bit since the preview.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

What you need to do is configure a scaleout-backplane for signalr so that messages can propagate between the nodes back to the user.

Here is a document that describes how to do it: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance-and-scaling/scaleout-with-windows-azure-service-bus

PS: there are other scaleout options besides the one used in this document, it's up to you.